# Yii: add prefix/postfix to model class naming

Tags: php, sql, yii

Is there any way I can get Yii to work with models that have a prefix or postfix in their class name?

For example, I have a table user, which corresponds to the model User. Now, I want this model to have a prefix, say, EmulatedUser. Is there any way to achieve that without renaming my table?

Answer (score 2):

The table and class name don't have to be the same. You can override the [`tableName`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#tableName-detail) in your model:

```
<?php
class EmulatedUser extends CActiveRecord {
   public function tableName() {
        return 'user';
   }
}
```